# .htaccess to block by file name possible?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a bunch of files that are secure_xxxxxx.php. Is there a way to use .htaccess to block access to all the secure_* php files based on IP?

EDIT:
I've tried but I get 500 errors

```
<FilesMatch "^secure_.*\.php$">
order deny all
deny from all
allow from my ip here
</FilesMatch>
```

Don't see any errors in apache error logs either

```
httpd -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 authn_file_module (static)
 authn_default_module (static)
 authz_host_module (static)
 authz_groupfile_module (static)
 authz_user_module (static)
 authz_default_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (static)
 include_module (static)
 filter_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 env_module (static)
 expires_module (static)
 headers_module (static)
 setenvif_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 proxy_module (static)
 proxy_connect_module (static)
 proxy_ftp_module (static)
 proxy_http_module (static)
 proxy_scgi_module (static)
 proxy_ajp_module (static)
 proxy_balancer_module (static)
 ssl_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mime_module (static)
 dav_module (static)
 status_module (static)
 autoindex_module (static)
 asis_module (static)
 info_module (static)
 suexec_module (static)
 cgi_module (static)
 dav_fs_module (static)
 negotiation_module (static)
 dir_module (static)
 actions_module (static)
 userdir_module (static)
 alias_module (static)
 rewrite_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 fastinclude_module (shared)
 auth_passthrough_module (shared)
 bwlimited_module (shared)
 frontpage_module (shared)
 suphp_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Files seem to work fine.

Comment: yes, you can at least make a rewrite rule based on ip.

Comment: Any examples? So far I've had 500 errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the Files directive and mod_authz_host to achieve you goals.

For example:

```
<Files "secure_*.php">
    Require 192.168.0.0/24
</Files>
```

See the references below.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html

Or using FilesMatch and the older ACL syntax:

```
<FilesMatch "^secure_.*\.php$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</FilesMatch>
```

This should only allow access from localhost.

Comment: Does it require PHP to be a certain mode? I got a 500 error with it

Comment: FilesMatch is what I would want to use maybe?

Comment: FilesMatch works, too. It's necessary if you want to use regular experessions in your match. PHP shouldn't be an issue here. If you are using an older version of Apache, you may need to use "allow" and "deny" instead of require. Check your Apache error log for more info.

Comment: Yea, I was using allow/deny but still 500'd on me. Appache is 2.2.23

Comment: I recommend updating your original question with the content of your .htaccess file and any relevant error messages from Apache's error log.

Comment: Probably just a typo in your edit, but that should be "Order Deny,Allow" (not "all"). Any luck with the error logs?

Comment: Nothing in the error logs. ;/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it's possible by using regular expression in .htaccess
http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Regular_Expressions_in_.htaccess

and also limitation based on IPs using `allow` and `deny` options.